# Loop through List elements saved as a string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string that consist of few List elements. I need to loop through these list elements and for this `each` statement is not working.
String have these list elements in this form

```
<li data-date="2018/03/23">item 1</li>
<li data-date="2018/04/18">item 2</li>
<li data-date="2018/03/08">item 3</li>
```

Here is the each statement that I have tried

```
store_list_temp.each(function() {

});
```

But it is causing an error. store_list_temp.each is not a function.

Is there a way to loop through these list elements which are stored as a string ?

Comment: Instead of just saying "not working," please post your code, so everyone can figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: Can you give an example of the string with your attempt(s) to loop through them? Stackoverflow isn't just about getting a working example but to also understand why your current attempt(s) didn't work.

Comment: I will add each statement in my question

Answer (score 3):

If each `li` are in different lines, you can split them by new line (`\n`). This will give you an array of `li` on which you can implement `forEach()` to get each `li` individually:

```js
var str = `<li data-date="2018/03/23">item 1</li>
<li data-date="2018/04/18">item 2</li>
<li data-date="2018/03/08">item 3</li>`

var strList = str.split('\n');
strList.forEach( (l,idx) => console.log(l + ` => at index ${(idx)}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. I'm not sure how you're using `store_list_temp`, but the error you're getting is because it doesn't evaluate to a function that returns something that you can iterate over using `each`. Presumably, it isn't such.

You need to understand how jQuery selectors work. To get going on that, I suggest that you read the [w3schools documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) on it. They are very similar to CSS selectors, so if you understand those, you have a running start.

This code will do what you want as specified in your post:

```
$('li').each(function() {

});
```

This will loop through the list items (in fact, it will loop through all the list items on your page) as you have them here. If you want to loop through a subset of the list elements on your page, then you'll have to learn how to assign classes in your HTML elements and specify them in your jQuery selector.

Comment: Actually I have to sort list elements based on 3 different criteria. So after implementing first 2 I have to save list elements in temp variable of same level and then call date sort function on list elements saved in a variable. My list elements which are of same level are saved in a variable and I have to loop through these elements. This is where I am struggling. I appreciate your help and time.

Comment: So, I believe that you are saying that you have to loop through a subset of your list elements, right?

Comment: @wpdd Then I suggest that you reread the last sentence of my post. Also, rather than saving list elements in a temp variable, I would use jQuery to add and remove a class that marks the elements you are going to work with in any given `each` loop. If, after working all that out, you still have trouble, I suggest you post another question with your specific problem, what you're trying to do, what's happening instead, and the code you've come up with.

Comment: I like your suggestion of adding and removing classes instead of saving these in a variable. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @wpdd You're very welcome. Good luck! If you come up with a working solution, it will help other people if you post it with an explanation. You're even allowed to accept it as an answer after 48 hours.